# After installation of Ubuntu alongside windows 7 boot menu shows Ubuntu, memory tester, Windows 7 how can I edit it?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-7

After installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 boot menu is showing Ubuntu,memory tester,windows 7 how can i edit it? I would like to see while rebooting the screen menu that would show windows 7 or Ubuntu to boot and I need to know how can I increase the font of boot menu?

Comment: how did you install it actually? could you please add info to your question from Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) run: `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` and paste those results to your question.

Comment: these are the ways of fixing the grub http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows if that what you are asking.

Comment: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265010/how-do-i-edit-grub-menu).