# Problem with deleting Windows-partition on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, delete

So far I've tried

1. using Disks in ubuntu applications. At first it appears as if the partition is indeed deleted but when I restart my computer I still get the choice to start in windows and doing so I am taken straight to a repair site.
2. I installed gparted and deleted the windows partition there and again it appears as if the windows partition is deleted but when I restart again I get a choice to start up in windows and this time there's not even a repair screen I am just taken straight to windows as if nothing happened.

What I want to do is delete the windows partition completely without a trace of it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit GRUB menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265010/how-do-i-edit-grub-menu)

Comment: since you have deleted windows partition, it gone for sure without any trace behind, now boot to Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @Virusboy, how is that a duplicate?

Comment: For the close voters, **this question is not a duplicate**

Answer (score 1):

The partition really should be deleted if you deleted in GParted. But there's still a GRUB entry, which starts the Windows boot loader, which can't find Windows any more.

**UEFI**: UEFI should be starting GRUB in order to boot Ubuntu. If it doesn so, remove every "windowsy" thing from the EFI partition. The EFI partition is mounted at `/boot/efi`. Look for a directory like `/boot/efi/EFI/Windows`.

**Legacy BIOS**: Note that most Windows installations keep their boot loader in a separate 100 MB partition. Delete this partition too, if it's still there.

Afterwards run `sudo update-grub` to remove the Windows boot loader from GRUB.