# How to uninstall dualboot Ubuntu 14 and Windows 8.1 dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall

So I used [This Tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) to install dualboot. I stopped at step 7 because everything was fine. Now I want to have it become just a normal Windows 8.1 machine. I have a USB recovery drive that I took as instructed. I really want to go back because GRUB scares me (don't ask why) and I wish it was as it was. I don't have a system recovery disk nor can I make one (though as I said I made that

Comment: sorry I pressed enter by mistake

Comment: I have the recovery USB that I made

Comment: If you do not need the disk space you can change the default menuentry to `windows 8.1 loader` and set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1`

Comment: Can you explain more in depth I don't understand

Comment: He means you want to change your grub configuration so that is defaults to windows 8 and the second flag makes it so that grub does not appear, it simply boots into the default option.  You can consult [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265010/how-do-i-edit-grub-menu) to see how.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a graphical frontend to tweak GRUB's configuration: 'grub-customizer'. I'll give you the link to where you find how to install it on Ubuntu. With this tool you can perform the settings described in the comments above without manually editing vital config files by just a few clicks. Maybe this can even help you to change GRUB in a way that you will like it. Greetings and have fun with it!

[How to install grub-customizer](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-1404/)