# Two Ubuntu options in boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I upgraded Ubuntu yesterday (from 14.something to 16.10 maybe :) ). The problem I have now is that I have two Ubuntu options in my boot menu. Grub Customizer shows the following (it indeed appears there are two Ubuntu versions.. is it possible that the "upgrade" actually installed a new version and kept the old one too or something??):[Grub Customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4buI.png)

Comment: Your Picture only shows one version and a series of advanced "Options" for Boot. If you want to edit your Grub Menu and remove those, there are instructions for that. http://askubuntu.com/questions/265010/how-do-i-edit-grub-menu

Comment: @EODCraft Staff  indeed, that's what it looks like strangely. But in the boot menu I have like two Ubuntu's, two "Advanced options for Ubuntu" (or so) and Windows (and some memory test as far as I remember). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

... should update your boot menu, have you tried that after the upgrade?

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't tried it, but after typing it and rebooting, I still see two options in my boot menu. I haven't actually tried selecting the second one.