# grub-mkconfig uses linux instead of linuxefi

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi

I have a dual boot **Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04**, I wanted to install **Centos 7** which I did.
*That broke my Ubuntu boot!*

- I deleted Centos 7 (partitions), deleted `/boot/efi/EFI/centos` folder

  - `/boot` is in a different partition
- Ran `grub-mkconfig -O /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- It keeps generating using `linux, initrd` instead of `linuxefi, initrdefi`.

**Why?**

FYI, my **secure boot is disabled** in the bios.

I'd like to just delete the whole `/boot/efi` partition and reinstall grub and the config. Is that possible? How about windows 10's boot?
I wish grub's information was much cleaner, it's so confusing.

Sources:
* [Modify GRUB permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975166/modify-grub-permanently)

Comment: Ubuntu does not use linuxefi nor initrdefi. the only real difference between UEFI boot and BIOS boot is the version of grub and some settings in fstab that grub updates, Maybe others.  You use grub-pc for BIOS boot and grub-efi-amd64 (if 64 bit Intel/AMD) for UEFI boot.

Comment: Your comment is even more confusing and doesn't help. If there is no difference and doesn't use `linuxefi, initrdefi`, why I can't boot ubuntu saying it can't find `linux and initrd`? And why I can finally boot ubuntu if I replace with `linuxefi`?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about `grub-pc or what`, I'm using grub installed by default with Ubuntu and only `grub-mkconfig`.

Comment: What are you doing ? You deleted the Centos partition and deleted `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. Why didn't you delete `/boot/efi/EFI/centos`. Seems you just killed Ubuntu's bootloader. I'd recommend to make use of [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to reinstall Ubuntu's grub. Do not delete the `/boot/efi`-partition, it would destroy WIndows bootloader as well.

Comment: Sorry mistyping, of course I deleted `/boot/efi/EFI/centos` folder. After using `boot-repair`, it worked. I wonder what boot-repair does more than `grub-mkconfig` and `grub-install`. Thanks!