# Disable older Ubuntu from boot list

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have a running Ubunutu 16.04LTS on a HDD. I installed a new SSD and Ubunutu 18.04LTS on it. Now, when I boot, I see the Grub list which shows HDD with 16.4LTS. I would like to directly boot into the new SSD with 18.04LTS and use the HDD for storage. How can I go directly booting to new OS and simply remove the older HDD from boot list?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/265010/how-do-i-edit-the-boot-order-in-the-grub-menu-to-have-windows-first#265015

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBlessen. I'd rather wish to remove older OS entry from the list than setting the timeout to 0.

Answer (score 0):

From [Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56004/how-to-stop-update-grub-from-scanning-all-drives) the easiest way is editing `/etc/default/grub` and inserting the line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Then save the file and run `sudo update-grub`.

If you have an older version of grub refer to the link for other options.